# FamilyEcho incorrectly lists my relationship as "ex-husband"

Tags: familyecho

I'm new to genealogy and started to build my tree in http://familyecho.com/ and after entering my initial family I noticed an issue in the information I so far have not been able to figure out.

- I started out with myself, and I added a lot of people including my wife. I found an option to specify relationship type and selected "married". I was then listed as her husband, and she as my wife. **OK!**
- **Problem:** Revisiting these fields I now discover that we are listed as "ex-husband" / "ex-wife" and I can't figure out how to fix that. I also don't know how it happened.
- I've exported the tree in GEDCOM format and in CSV format. It looks like the error is in my record, but I see no way to fix it:
- In the CSV format, there's a column "partner" and a column "ex-partner" -- all records are correct except mine which holds the reference to my wife in the "ex-partner" column.
- In the GEDCOM export file, I can see a line `1 FAMS @F6@` where "F6" is the reference to my wife; but I don't see anywhere in GEDCOM that specifies the relationship type, specifically the erroneous "ex-" part.
- **The Issue:** I found my marriage lines in the end of the GEDCOM file where the and noticed a line reading "2 TYPE Ending" underneath "1 EVEN". To my untrained eye, this seems to be the culprit - is it indicating that the marriage is noted as ending? That's not actually the case, but I can't see how I can correct it in the web application.

As I've already shared this tree with family members, I'd rather not hand-edit the GEDCOM 5.5.1 formatted file and upload it into a new tree as I attempted that but it didn't seem to work.

How do I fix this incorrect end of relationship in FamilyEcho?

Comment: Welcome to [genealogy.se], I have made some minor formatting edits to question. Please be sure to take the [tour] and review the [help] section of this site as to what is in scope and how to refine your question. If you have further updates please use the 'edit' button and update the question appropriately vs. adding "updates" to the bottom for example.

Answer (score 4):

I took a look and played a bit and editing of the relationships seems pretty straight forward and I seemed to be able to edit it from either partner.

I had to just go select "Me" and go into "Partners" and change the relationship type and change it back married AND remove any divorce date. At one point it momentarily appeared I could only change it from one side, but then found I could change it from either side of the relationship.

I did not attempt to have either individual listed as having multiple partners, which may create the scenario in the software of defaulting the ones with earlier or undefined marriage dates to ex-partners which I have seen a few software packages do in the distant past.. but that doesn't seem to be your scenario being the most recent partner.

[image]

[image]

If this doesn't address it could be an issue with the site itself as I couldn't create a relationship intentionally I couldn't change and fix.

One thing to consider is this [FamilyEcho](http://www.familyecho.com/) site seems to be a new home grown Genealogy site software only hosted on the one system and in its early beginnings and with a lot of limitations and things take significantly longer to enter information than many other packages *(at least for me)*. So if you want to stick to non-commercial software and want to stay in GEDCOM format I would suggest taking a look at [GRAMPS](https://gramps-project.org/) that is open source and has a large user community, and since you are in Austria I would suggest you also maybe take a look at the German language program [Familienbande](http://www.familienbande-genealogie.de/) which has some interesting and unique features I haven't seen in other programs. A list of many other packages are also available on [Cyndi's list](http://www.cyndislist.com/software/genealogy/?page=1).

Then if you want to use [FamilyEcho](http://www.familyecho.com/) as a secondary tool to share or perform visualizations you can upload the latest GEDCOM or subset GEDCOM.

No matter what software you choose as your primary package I would identify a secondary package and ensure your data imports cleanly from it and backup your GEDCOM regularly and test it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm aware of Gramps but I was looking for an online collaborative tool rather than a locally installed one. I also found one operated by the latter day saints.... I'm not religious and would rather not be involved there, but it looks neat. More later!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by editing the "married" relationship: I set the wedding date and location to nothing (divorce was already blank), then set the type to blank and saved.

Then I edited the person again (I was editing my wife's profile but I guess I could just as well have edited my own) and filled in the marriage details again.

It looks fine now. - Apparently something was incorrectly "stuck" in the existing relationship and removing it completely got rid of that.